# Problema no roteamento após o build final em angular 2

Tags: angular, ngroute, router

Após gerar um build final em angular 2 `ng build --prod` Consegui coloca-lo em um servidor qualquer (nginx/tomcat/outros...) normalmente, o problema acontece que o roteamento não funciona utilizando a tag `<router-outlet>` e o arquivo app.routing.ts para configurar as rotas. Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido com routerLink no link abaixo

https://github.com/diegolirio/ci-jenkins-docker/commit/55e3d3f9c65e4289ff93509a6e7e48ab4923f165

Se o conteúdo for um **module** adicional deverá importar também o **routing** componente nesse novo **module**.

Answer (score 0):

Simples se tem de por numa pasta utilize :

**ng build --base-href /myUrl/**
ou
**ng build --bh /myUrl/**

Por exemplo eu tenho de por o site numa directiva chamada site2 então 
**ng build --bh /site2/**

Mais Informações https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Answer (score 0):

Possivelmente você está utilizando algo do tipo

```
<a class="nav-link" href="/contatos">Contatos</a>
```

Utilizando o `href="Diretório-da-rota"` funciona até fazer o *build* e depois não funciona mais. Você deverá utilizar o `routerLink="Diretório-da-rota"`.
Exemplo:

```
<a routerLink="/contatos" class="nav-link">Contatos</a>
```